# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} x^2\left(1+2+3+...+\left[ \frac{1}{|x|} \right] \right)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I was thinking about the squeeze theorem here. We can denote the $\left[\frac{1}{|x|}\right] =n$, and then try something like:

$$x^2(1+2+3+...+(n-1)+(n-1)) \leq x^2 \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \leq x^2(1+2+3+...+(n-1)+(n+1))$$

But I don't know what to do with $x^2$. Given that $\left[ \frac{1}{|x|} \right]=n$, how do we proceed to find $x^2$?

Comment: You can't find $x^2$ from $n$. At least, not directly. But you can find quite good bounds on the value of the expression on the interval $(\frac1{n+1},\frac1n]$ for any natural number $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that 
$$\left[\frac1{|x|}\right]=n$$
we have
$$n\le\frac1{|x|}<n+1$$
Therefore
$$\frac1n\ge|x|>\frac1{n+1}$$
and thus,
$$\frac1{(n+1)^2}<x^2\le\frac1{n^2}$$

Because you seem worry only about an upper bound of the function, I feel that you expect that the limit is $0$. I think it isn't...

Comment: using that upper bound for $x^2$ I get $0.5$. Think it's correct.

Comment: You need also a lower bound to apply squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

First we may suppose $x> 0$ as well. Next, 
$$\biggl\lfloor\frac1x\biggr\rfloor=n\iff n\le\frac1x<n+1, \enspace\text{ so }\enspace x\dots$$

Answer (score 0):

Why not just substitute $x=1/n$ (noting that the limits from both sides are the same) and consider $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac1{n^2}(1+2+\cdots+n)$$ 
instead?

Comment: You can't find a limit of a function with a limit of a sequence.

Comment: @ajotatxe : If it has a monotone tail, yes you can

Comment: @ajotatxe : Hmm, I see that the tail isn't necessarily monotone, so your objection may have merit. I will reconsider.

Comment: @ajotatxe : Wait a minute -- if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists (say it is $L$), and the sequence $a_n\to a$, then certainly $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f(a_n) =L$. How is this different, other than needing to first show the limit exists? (My comment about monotonicity was to ensure the limit exists.)

Comment: @MPW "needing to first show the limit exists" That's exactly it. The expression given in the problem isn't monotone (it decreases continuously as $x\to 0$, but then increases discontinuously each time $\frac1x$ is an integer).